# C# generic error in GDI+ during saving an image using Spire.Pdf libirary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A
>   generic error occurred in GDI+.    at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String
>   filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)

```
public  static List<string> ConvertPdfToImage(string strPdfSource)
 {
            lock (ConvertPdfToImageLocker)
            {
                var listImages = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                    using (var pdfDoc = new Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument())
                    {
                        string strPdfResult = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(strPdfSource);
                        string strPdfname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strPdfResult);
                        pdfDoc.LoadFromFile(strPdfResult);
                        //save to images
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdfDoc.Pages.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string strFileNameImage = "~/assets/result_request_image/" + strPdfname + "_"+i + ".Png";
                            string strImageSource = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(strFileNameImage);
                            using (Image image = pdfDoc.SaveAsImage(i, Spire.Pdf.Graphics.PdfImageType.Metafile, 150, 150))
                            {

                                if (strImageSource != null) image.Save(strImageSource, ImageFormat.Png);
                            }
                            listImages.Add(strImageSource);
                        }
                        pdfDoc.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Ilog.Error(exception.ToString());
                }

                return listImages;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Check the Permission or path if it's invalid (this 2 are common issue most of time)

Comment: Can you write your question? Sometimes code is not enought

Comment: I am getting the same error on pdf.SaveAsImage